# How to use "full" of wrap_content, created by other views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-wrap-content

Currently im working on a fine ui. Now i came to this:
[image]

Im stucking on the "profile_layout" on the left side with the muffin inside. 
For the two bars on the right side im using wrap_content.

But now im stucking to let the profile_layout use the full height of the "wrap_content" from the two bars.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/top_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="8dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            >

            <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/muffin"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                app:border="true"
                app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
                app:border_width="4dp"
                app:shadow="true"
                />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#212121"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Muffin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/hp_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="3dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hp_text"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:text="HP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/hp_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:progress="43"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/hp_bar"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hp_currently"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="43/100"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/mp_bar_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/hp_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="3dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mp_text"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:text="MP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/mp_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:progress="17"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mp_bar"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mp_currently"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="17/100"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your cardview enclosing the muffin- layout_height to match_parent. Comment if that doesnt fix it

EDIT: Ok so after some more thinking i figured out that Relative Layout is causing the problem here. Here you can completely delete the relative layout or replace it with a linear layout. At the end to fix your problem the cardview must have height as match_parent and its immediate parent(enclosing tag) must be anything but a Relative Layout with height as wrap_content

Comment: did you edit the correct cardview? the one with the muffin imageview in it?

Comment: Yes, the cardview stretches to the whole screen.

Comment: just deleted the relativelayout now and set the cardview height to match_parent, and it works, thank you very much! :D

Comment: check this question-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303410/match-parent-property-for-children-in-a-relativelayout

it has another solution in case you absolutely have to have relative layout as the parent

Answer (score 0):

You must use LinearLayouts like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <!-- You may give a definite value too -->

    <ImageView
        android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding_large"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appIcon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding_large"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/appName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/appDeveloper" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`, and align the top & bottom of the first child to the second. And of course, set the second child `toRightOf` the fist one. Then, `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` the CardView of the first child.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"

            android:id="@+id/column_1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/column_2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/column_2"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"

                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                >

                <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/muffin"
                    app:border="true"
                    app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
                    app:border_width="4dp"
                    app:shadow="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="Muffin"
                    android:textColor="#212121" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"

            android:id="@+id/column_2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column_1"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/hp_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hp_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:text="HP"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/hp_bar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:progress="43"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/hp_bar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hp_currently"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:text="43/100"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/mp_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/hp_bar_layout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mp_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:text="MP"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/mp_bar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:progress="17"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mp_bar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mp_currently"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:text="17/100"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```